# Why does the ceiling have to be so high up in large supermarkets?

Tags: structural-engineering

I just noticed this while watching a stream in Thailand, but this also seems to apply to the West (where I live) and the USA and everywhere because everything is globalized and standardized these days.

Basically, the ceiling/roof is way, way up there, seemingly for no reason. Why don't they put the ceiling much closer to the humans shopping for food? Why must it be so high up? Is this some kind of ventilation thing or something? Doesn't it cost much more to make a building so enormous in height and have to heat up a much larger volume of space?

I don't understand why it's not like a normal room. Then they could put another level on top or just save the money.

Answer (score 2):

there are several reasons.

- Fire hazard: A space as large as these big box floor areas have to be divided into smaller fire skirts on the ceiling to contain the spread of a potential fire. If you look up to the ceiling you will see it is being partitioned by either corrugated sheets or some other noncombustible material hanging from the ceiling into a square pattern of parapets.
- Storage space of the merchandise stacked up and enough height for the lift trucks to easily move them up and down. The storage is right above the merchandise.
- Architectural considerations. A short very large space ceiling is not flattering at all, would not have a pleasant scale, and look welcoming, worse when it is cluttered with suspended signs.
- Acoustics, It will reflect and amplify the noises.